# Conditional logic form

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to program a form with some conditional logic. I will give you guys an example what i want to do.

Question 1: Do you have your warranty form?

- Yes
- No

If the visitor pressed yes I want to show the following:

Question 2: Purchase date?

- Write here ur text.

I got the following code already:

Code question 1

```
        <div class="form-section-content2">
    <div class="first-label-column-1-grey">
        <div class="form-content">
            Garantie bewijs meegeleverd *
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first-label-column-2-grey">
        <div class="form-content">
            <input class="form-field" type="radio" name="garantie" value="ja"> Ja</br>
            <input class="form-field" type="radio" name="garantie" value="nee"> Nee
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code question 2

```
  <div class="form-section-content1">
    <div class="first-label-column-1-white">
        <div class="form-content">
            Aanschafdatum *
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first-label-column-2-white">
        <div class="form-content">
            <input class="form-field-text" type="text" name="aanschafdatum">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tryed something with php and javascript but can't get it done. If you guys could help me would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the JavaScript `onChange` event to run a function whenever the radio button is clicked.  You can then show a `<div>` based on which button was clicked.

```js
function displayQuestion(answer) {

  document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

  if (answer == "yes") { // hide the div that is not selected

    document.getElementById('noQuestion').style.display = "none";

  } else if (answer == "no") {

    document.getElementById('yesQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }

}
```

```html
<form name="feedback" action="javascript:void(0)">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />Yes</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />No</label>

  <div id="yesQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>
    Why did you choose yes?
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer here . . . " />
  </div>

  <div id="noQuestion" style="display:none;"><br/>
    Why did you choose no?
    <input type="text" placeholder="answer here . . . " />
  </div>

<br/><br/><input type="submit">

</form>
```

Hope that helps!